# Is Stack Overflow a good place to ask specific sympy questions?

Tags: support, questions, scope

Questions like such as: How to do X in sympy? E.g. questions which touch math as well as programming.
(Not questions such as: "How to install sympy on OS Y?")

Is there a better place than Stack Overflow - on Stack Exchange or any other Q&A platform - to ask those questions?

Comment: A search of Stackoverflow returned over 1800 questions tagged [sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sympy/topusers) of which almost 80% have been answered.  While the entire rest of the network produced only about 30 questions combined.

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks! Of course, tags do not give the full answer, e.g. : https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sympy

Comment: I'd say we should treat them like any other scientific tool or framework. If the core of the question is about the technical use of the framework and the understanding of its API, then it's on-topic. Just because there is an API for an automatic cooking device doesn't mean that cooking recipes are on-topic, for example.

Comment: Note: if you stop at "How to do X in sympy?" your question will be rightfully downvoted for lack of demonstrated research, but presumably you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents - yes, they are, as long as the question focuses on the use of SymPy and how to convert a well understood and/or explain mathematic problem to it, and not on the math itself - which will probably fit better of [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: MathSE dislikes programming.... I think maybe cs would be a better match, but note, most of the SymPy questions were asked here (1800) and 2/3 of them is answered.